# "or" boolean in an inline "if" statement

Tags: python

I have a program that begins by parsing several arguments, one of which is a "verbose" flag. However, I also have a "simulate" flag, which I would like to automatically flip the verbose flag to "True" if it is on.

Right now I have this working:

```
if args.verbose or simulate:  
    verbose = True
```

How can I get this onto one line? I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
verbose = True if args.verbose or simulate
```

or like:

```
verbose = True if (args.verbose or simulate)
```

While searching here, I found a solution that fits on one line:

```
verbose = (False, True)[args.verbose or simulate]
```

However, I find that solution to be much less readable than the others that I was hoping would work. Is this possible, and I'm just missing something? Or is it not possible to use an "or" between two checks for "True" like this in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with `or`, it's that you need an `else` clause to specify what the value should be if the `if` statement fails. Otherwise, what is getting assigned if the condition is false?

```
verbose = True if args.verbose or simulate else False
```

There's no need for the `if` at all, though. It's even simpler if you just assign the result of the test to `verbose` directly:

```
verbose = args.verbose or simulate
```

Answer (score 1):

A *functionally equivalent* expression would be:

```
verbose = True if args.verbose or simulate else verbose
```

since it is possible that `verbose` is already `True`, or something else (a number, a list, a dictionary, etc.)

Furthermore if we are not sure `arg.verbose` and `simulate` are booleans, we can not use:

```
verbose = arg.verbose or simulate
```

since if for example `simulate` is `[1]`, then we get:

```
>>> False or [1]
[1]
```

We can however convert this expression to a boolean, like:

```
verbose = bool(arg.verbose or simulate) or verbose
```

here in case the condition is `False`, we assign `verbose` back to `verbose` (since again it is possible that `verbose` has been set to something other than `False`).

If however both simulate and `verbose` are known to be booleans, we can use:

```
verbose = arg.verbose or simulate or verbose
```

In case it is known that `verbose` has been set to `False` initially:

```
verbose = arg.verbose or simulate
```

is sufficient. In that case we can skip the previous initialization of `verbose` (given it is not used between the initialization and setting it here).